# Insert value with select statement, or if it doesn't exist insert new value

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update, sql-insert

I am trying to execute a query in SQL Server where I update a row and if it doesn't exist, create a row. This works fine, but within my Insert statement for creating a new row I need to select a value from that table for `_idref uniqueidentifier`.

The case I am running into is if there are no possible values returned from the select, I need to add a fresh unique identifier using `NEWID()`.

Here is my query:

```
DECLARE @LGRACT BIGINT
DECLARE @SUBACT BIGINT
DECLARE @AMOUNT DECIMAL(12,2)
DECLARE @PostYear SMALLINT
DECLARE @PostMonth TINYINT

SET @PostYear = 2018
SET @PostMonth = 12
SET @LGRACT = 6000
SET @SUBACT = 200
SET @AMOUNT = 2000.00

UPDATE [Services Copy].dbo.lgrbal 
SET balance = ((SELECT balance 
                FROM [Services Copy].dbo.lgrbal
                WHERE lgract = @LGRACT 
                  AND postyr = @PostYear 
                  AND actprd = @PostMonth) + @AMOUNT) 
WHERE lgract = @LGRACT 
  AND postyr = @PostYear 
  AND actprd = @PostMonth

IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0
    INSERT INTO [Services Copy].dbo.lgrbal (_idnum, _idref, lgract, postyr, actprd, balance)
    VALUES (NEWID(),
            (SELECT TOP 1 _idref 
             FROM [Services Copy].dbo.lgrbal 
             WHERE lgract = @LGRACT 
               AND postyr = @PostYear) 
             WHERE NOT EXISTS NEWID()),
       @LGRACT, @PostYear, @PostMonth, @AMOUNT)
```

You can see in the `INSERT INTO VALUES` section, I am doing a `select top 1` for the `_idref` returned for the account and year.

If it is January though, there will be no other records stored and I have no `_idref` returned.

In this case, I would need to just replace the select with a `NEWID()`.

Comment: Make another variable and before your insert check for the _idref value is null, then set it to the NEWID, ELSE use your SELECT.

Comment: You can also simplify things using the MERGE command:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/merge-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Felipe-Martins commented, a MERGE statement might make things a bit easier.

MERGE doesn't explicitly solve the specific question you had about dynamically re-using  an existing _idref or generating a new one via newid(), but that's easily solved by wrapping an `isnull()` call around your subquery.

There's probably a better solution, but there hasn't been much activity on this in the first hour since you posted so I figured I'd save this post rather than throw it away in case it helps.

```
declare @LGRACT bigint
declare @SUBACT bigint
declare @AMOUNT decimal(12,2)
declare @PostYear smallint
declare @PostMonth tinyint
set @PostYear=2018
set @PostMonth=12
set @LGRACT = 6000
set @SUBACT = 200
set @AMOUNT = 2000.00

MERGE [Services Copy].dbo.lgrbal AS target  
USING (SELECT @LGRACT, @AMOUNT, @PostYear, @PostMonth) AS source 
      (lgract, amount, postyr, actprd)  
ON (
    target.lgract = source.lgract and 
    target.postyr = source.postyr and
    target.actprd = source.actprd
)  
WHEN MATCHED THEN   
    UPDATE SET target.Balance = target.Balance + source.amount
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT (
        _idnum, 
        _idref, 
        lgract, 
        postyr, 
        actprd, 
        balnce
    )  
    VALUES (
        newid(),
        isnull(
            (select top 1 _idref 
            from [Services Copy].dbo.lgrbal 
            where lgract=@LGRACT and postyr=@PostYear), 
            newid()),
        source.lgract, 
        source.postyr, 
        source.actprd, 
        source.balance
    )
```

Comment: Thank you.  I haven't used Merge before but after seeing this I will play around with it some more for other scenarios I know it will work on.

Comment: Be very careful with MERGE. https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3074/use-caution-with-sql-servers-merge-statement/

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is an industry standard, but I call this type of operation an "Upsert".

This is my typical way of handling that, on a stored procedure.

```
IF (EXISTS(SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE IdColumn = @IdParameter)) BEGIN   
    -- UPDATE 
    UPDATE TABLE_NAME 
    SET columns appropriately
    WHERE IdColumn = @IdParameter 
END 
ELSE 
BEGIN   
-- INSERT
    SET @IdParameter= NEWID();

    INSERT INTO TABLE_NAME 
    SELECT @IdParameter,
    @OtherParams

END

EXEC usp_Select_YourObject @IdParameter; -- other stored proc that handles the object to be returned. ;
```

Obviously, that's more of a generic approach. Your case still applies though. I would query the table to see if the row exists first. If it does, update it accordingly. If it doesn't, insert a new one with a new ID.